# Route model binding issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a set of code, it is similar to the other codes that I'm using and they are working fine. Just in this case there is some mysterious issue which I'm not able to find the cause of. Please see the code below

**BlogPostController.php**

```
    public function category(Category $category){
        return view('blog/cat')->with('categories',$category);
    }
```

**categories.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.blog')

    {‌{$categories->name}}
```

The `category.blade` does not output `{‌{$categories->name}}`  . No errors are shown. If I change the `{‌{$categories->name}}`  and type normal text e.g `data` , then `data` is printed on the webpage . I even tried restarting my system. There is no way out.

The I removed the Model Route Binding, and tried the usual way ,

```
public function category($id){
    $category = Category::where('id',$id)->first();
    return view('blog/cat')->with('categories',$category);
}
```

**EDIT**
**ROUTE - web.php**

```
Route::get('blog/category/{cat}','BlogPostController@category')->name('blog.category');
```

In this case the `category.blade.php` prints the data properly.

What could be the issue with the Model Route Binding in this case. All my controllers use Model Route Binding rather than the usual way, but this is the first time I'm stumbling upon this issue.

Comment: Add `Log::info($category);` above the return view, then check your logs in `storage/logs/` to see what it printed out.

Comment: Please post your route to this controller and I will update my answer with the corrected version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From:** [laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

#### Implicit Binding

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.

So try to do:

```php
Route::get('blog/category/{category}','BlogPostController@category')->name('blog.category');
```

#### Explicit Binding

> To register an explicit binding, use the router's model method to specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your explicit model bindings in the boot method of the  RouteServiceProvider class

Or use **Explicit Binding**

***RouteServiceProvider.php***

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('cat', App\Category::class);
}
```

And you can still use:

```php
Route::get('blog/category/{cat}','BlogPostController@category')->name('blog.category');
```

Answer (score 3):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding

```
Route::get('blog/category/{category}','BlogPostController@category')->name('blog.category');
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a new information. And it worked.