# How to pass parameter to a route

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this for each "project"

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$project->proj_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$client->find($project->client_id)->client_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_at}}</td>
            @if (Auth::user()->role=='admin')
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>                                                  
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.edit',$project)}}">Edit</a>

                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('projects.destroy',$project)}}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">
                        @method('DELETE')
                        @csrf
                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit">Delete</button>
            @endif
    ------------>       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.tasks',$project)}}">tasks</a>

                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
            </td>


        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Where I need help is in the line `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.tasks',$project)}}">tasks</a>`

That route goes to my controller:

```
Route::get('/projects/tasks', ['as' => 'projects.tasks', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@seeTasks']);
```

I need to pass that controller the id of the project in which I clicked so I can display all the tasks linked to it. I already have all relations done I just need help with this part.
I don't know what I need to do to accomplish this.

This is the function I have for now in my controller:

```
public function seeTasks(Project $project){
    return $project;

}
```

It returns an empty array `[]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Route model binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692087/route-model-binding-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you need to use route model biding. So your route definition will be

```php
Route::get('/projects/{project}/tasks', ['as' => 'projects.tasks', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@seeTasks']);
```

Laravel will automatically fetch the project you pass to the route, or raise an exception if the model does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my solution.

Comment: Please consider marking it as the answer to your question.

Comment: To complete what Francinaldo Almeida said, here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) for Laravel Route Parameters.